# Can I query VSTS to get counts of Pull Request approvals

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to have a list of team members and the count of pull requests they've approved. I'm not sure if I can do this through the standard VSTS portal, or if I would have to create a custom report using BI tools.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such filter/configuration for standard VSTS to do it.

But you can achieve similar features from [**Pull Request Search**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.pull-request-search) **extension** in marketplace.

In the extension, you can filter pull request by status and reviewer, so it will list pull requests which for a certain user approved.

[image]

Or you can develop with your own extension to achieve it.